# Cannot kill NodeJS process that always keeps restarting

Tags: node.js

I started a node script inside WebStorm once. It is a VueJS application. It is running on localhost:5000. When I open it inside chrome, I can see that it first is not responding, and then it suddenly loads. That tells me that the process is always restarting and inside a loop.
When I run `ps aux | grep node` , I can see the process quickly changing the process ID. That confirms my observation. If I try to kill the process it tells me that there is no process with that ID because it restarted that quickly. The process also is starting when  reboot the computer. I also completely uninstalled NodeJS from my computer, but strangely it is starting anyways. I'm on macOS and I don't know what I could try anymore.

`ps aux | grep node`  output:

`2959   0,0  0,0  4268464    740 s000  S+    3:47pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox node`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment on your question, so I'm writing here.

It seems like you're application somehow registered in the service which happened to me as well. Mine was CentOS7.

You can check if it's added into service and run automatically whenever the machine is on. The command is Linux ones, so I'm not sure whether it's gonna work on MacOS as well.

//check list

```
chkconfig --list
```

//turn off the automatic start

```
chkconfig [your application name] off
```

If changing service config by using above commands did not work, you can search for the Mac Service Script. I think service shell script are different. Again, my case was on CentOS7.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I looked up the equivalent for macOS. It is "launchctl list". But I could not find a service that looked matching. I also checked if I can find a PID that could roughly match but there wasn't one. :/

Comment: What about `sudo luanchctl list` with/without `sudo` displays different list. `sudo` will display all.